# Strong Signing, and Updating A Referencing Assembly

Tags: .net, assemblies, code-signing, strongname

I have two, third party assemblies:

`Foo.dll`

and

`ReferencesFoo.dll`

As noted, `ReferencesFoo.dll` is an assembly that has a reference to `Foo.dll`

For my application, I need to resign these assemblies. I use ildasm/ilasm in combination along with a signing key to resign them, however, `ReferencesFoo.dll` still contains (in it's manifest?) the reference to the `Foo.dll` old public key and public key token.

So, how do I sign both dll's with my key, and update the references in `ReferencesFoo.dll` without getting the source code and recompiling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sign an assembly with the SN.exe tool (using the -R switch to resign an already signed assembly).

But you have to be aware that modifying a third party component might likely be illegal. So make sure there are no legal problems before doing so.

And I'm not aware of any tools to automatically change references. You can find them in the metadatatable #35 which is structured as follows:

- MajorVersion, MinorVersion,
  BuildNumber, RevisionNumber (2-byte
  constants)
- Flags (a 4-byte bitmask of type
  AssemblyFlags)
- PublicKeyOrToken (index into Blob
  heap – the public key or token that
  identifies the author of this
  Assembly)
- Name (index into String heap)
- Culture (index into String heap)
- HashValue (index into Blob heap)

Comment: Added explanation of where to find the references to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do that with [Mono.Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil). Open Foo.dll, and [save it with your new snk](http://wiki.github.com/jbevain/cecil/strongname), and update its reference in ReferenceFoo.dll to the appropriate public key token.

Answer (score 2):

I found this article which demonstrates exactly how to do this.

It involved using sn,ildasm,ilasm, and a text editor.

http://buffered.io/posts/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing